# Android Studio -- Double install the same project in android phone

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I have an android studio project, when I connect my phone to the laptop and I install the application, it replace the old one, but I want 2 applications I want to install the new one modified with the old one because I need them both, And even if I try to change the name of the applications they replace the other one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android looks to the `applicationId` to know if you're installing the same application (replace) or not. The easiest way to have the same application installed twice, is to change the `applicationId` in your `build.gradle` file.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id